# Can't reach localhost:8080 while running docker image

Tags: java, docker, web-applications, localhost

I have developed a small Java demo web app, using gradle, which I want to dockerize with WildFly. I have followed instructions from [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/jboss/wildfly/).

The `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM jboss/wildfly
MAINTAINER Me <me@qmail.com>

RUN /opt/jboss/wildfly/bin/add-user.sh admin Admin#70365 --silent

ADD build/libs/my-demo.war /opt/jboss/wildfly/standalone/deployments/
```

When I start the image with Docker and browse `localhost:8080` or `localhost:9990`, I get a `This site can’t be reached`.

Yet, my application runs successfully on `localhost:8080` when I use `gradle appRun`.

What is missing?

I am under Windows 10 Home Edition. I have tried on another laptop under Ubuntu 16 and face the same issue.

Comment: localhost does not work this way.  It will look for server on your Window envi rather than getting inside the running container.  Can you share the docker run command you used?

Comment: It's `docker run -it my-demo`

Comment: There may be a few issues.  Can you add the following line to your docker file and see if it works:  EXPOSE 8080 9990

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three things:

**1st**
the base image `EXPOSE`s only port 8080, so to be able to access port *9990* you need to add `EXPOSE 9990` to your Dockerfile or `--expose 9990` to your `docker run`call.

**2nd**
You didn't post your cmd line call, so I can only guess but you need to map the container port to a host port, example (including the additional exposed port)

```
docker run --expose 9990 -p 9990:9990 -p 8080:8080 -it my-demo
```

**3rd**
If your working with docker-machine as it is still the case with Win 10 home as far as I recall, you won't have your application on localhost but at the IP of the docker-machine VM. You can find out which IP that is by calling

```
docker-machine ip
```

On linux you will have your app on localhost:PORT once you add the port mapping.

Comment: I've managed to run `docker-machine`, but I had to use lowercase for IP.

Comment: +1  `docker-machine ip` was the solution for me.  I was following these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-tutorial-prepare-app.